# How to implement a counter for each element of a python list?

Tags: python, list, counter

Using Python 3.4

I've got a way that works, but I think there might be a better way.
I want to have a list with a method `expand()` which chooses a random element from the list, but every time that element is chosen, a counter is incremented. I tried subclassing `str` to be able to add attributes but it didn't work.

My main problem with what I've got is that the expression `random.randint(0,len(self)-1)` and using a local variable doesn't seem very Pythonic. Before I added the counter, I could just type `random.choice(self)`

```
class clauses(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.uses = []

    def __setitem__(self,key,value):
        self.uses[key]=value
        super().__setitem__(self,key,value)

    def __delitem__(self,key):
        del(self.uses[key])
        super().__delitem__(key)

    def append(self,value):
        self.uses.append(0)
        super().append(value)

    def extend(self,sequence):
        for x in sequence:
            self.uses.append(0)
            super().append(x)

    def expand(self):

        n = random.randint(0,len(self)-1)

        self.uses[n] += 1
        return(self[n])
```

Comment: What will happen to the counters if a particular element is removed?

Comment: instead of `random.randint(0, len(self) - 1)` use `random.randrange(0, len(self))`, which has existed ever since Python 1.5.2

Comment: should `self.uses[key]=value` be instead `self.uses[key] = 0`? Seems that otherwise you're setting the counter to the value in the list...

Comment: Note also that `list` supports slice indexing (i.e. the `key` in `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` could be a slice object).

Comment: @6502 Yes it should be = 0 - hasn't come up in testing, because I've only used append and extend. I think slicing is unlikely to be an issue due to context - this is a tree for parts on an English sentence, so slicing wouldn't make sense.

Comment: What about also initializing a dictionary that keeps track of the counts?  This would need to be updated each time an item is added to or removed from the list.  Each item could be set to `myDict[element] = 0` when added and `myDict[element]+=1` when chosen...

Comment: @FortyLashes I considered this - would there be a problem if two elements of the list were the same though? I think that's actually very unlikely to happen, so this might be the best way of doing it!

Comment: @thefourtheye there should be a line deleting that counter - thank you.

Comment: @JamesWilson There would be a problem if two items in the list were identical, as we can't have two identical keys in a Python dictionary.  I will submit my suggestion as an answer to this question, if it works for you, feel free to mark it as solved.

Comment: @FortyLashes Just use list indices as the dict keys? If items can be repeated then the count clearly isn't semantically tied to the item value anyway. (And if it were, dict of item:count would be exactly what you'd want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing an empty dictionary, along with your list should solve this, assuming there are no duplicate entries within the list.

When adding an element to the list, you can also add it to the dictionary by `myDict[element]=0` where `myDict` is the initialized dictionary, and `element` is the item being added to the list.

Then, when the item is selected, you can simply do: `myDict[element]+=1`.

When dealing with an instance of duplicate entries, you could create a dictionary of dictionaries in which each `key` in the dictionary is a word, and the nested dictionary `keys` for each word are, say, index positions of the duplicate word (the values of course being the actual counts).  This does add substantial complication, however, as when you remove an item from your list you will need to also update index positions.  This nested data structure would like something like this though: `{ word1: {position1: count1}, word2: {position1: count1, position 2: count2}....}`

Comment: Thanks @FortyLashes, I think a dictionary is the way to go. Now I've thought about it, the duplicate behaviour will be okay, as this is a counter for how many times an element of a phrase has been used. If I create a new key each time a new element is added, and just increase the counter any other time, it should work. In fact, it should work better!

Comment: @JamesWilson Please accept my answer as being the solution to your problem.